# Parametrizar busqueda en EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Tengo que realizar una búsqueda en una DB con EF, y esta búsqueda permite que sea masiva ya normalmente se usará para buscar +5000 registros. Además cuenta con varios JOINS pero ya realice las querys para que realice la menor cantidad de trabajo en MSSM con el profiler pero todavía necesito mejorar algo. Esta por ejemplo es una de las querys que uso:

```
listaDatosPersonales = await db.Clientes.Where(cliente => listaIds.Contains(cliente.IdEntidadDeNegocio) && !cliente.Borrado).ToListAsync();
```

El problema es que realiza un query text de esta manera:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
    FROM [Cliente].[Clientes] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] IN (428835, 428836, 428837,...
```

Y la X cantidad de ids que le mando en la query. Hay alguna manera de parametrizar esto con Entity Framework?

La lista de ids la realizo buscando registros que se filtran por un predicado:

```
var listaIds = await db.Clientes.Where(predicado).Select(x => x.Id).ToArrayAsync();
```

Gracias!

Comment: Y si usaras el método intersect de linq para ver los ID que hay en común entre las dos listas

Comment: Hola @Japv, no entiendo en que me serviría usar el metodo intersect para evitar que el query text no salga parametrizado.

Comment: que error te sale?